# Object oriented vs vector based programming

Tags: python, performance, oop, numpy, vectorization

I am torn between object oriented and vector based design. I love the abilities, structure and safety that objects give to the whole architecture. But at the same time, speed is very important to me, and having simple float variables in an array really helps in vector based languages/ libraries like Matlab or numpy in Python.

Here is a piece of code I wrote to illustrate my point

Problem: Adding Tow volatility numbers. If x and y are two volatility numbers, the sum of the volatility is (x^2 + y^2)^0.5 (assuming certain mathematical condition but that's not important here).

I want to perform this operation very fast, and at the same time I need to ensure that people don't just add the volatility in the wrong way (x+y). Both of these are important.

The OO based design would be something like this:

```
from datetime import datetime 
from pandas import *

class Volatility:
    def __init__(self,value):
       self.value = value

    def __str__(self):
       return "Volatility: "+ str(self.value)

    def __add__(self,other):
        return Volatility(pow(self.value*self.value + other.value*other.value, 0.5))
```

(Aside: For those who are new to Python, **add** is just a function that overrides the '+' operator)

Let's say I add tow lists of volatility values

```
n = 1000000
vs1 = Series(map(lambda x: Volatility(2*x-1.0), range(0,n)))
vs2 = Series(map(lambda x: Volatility(2*x+1.0), range(0,n)))
```

(Aside: Again, a Series in Python is sort of a list with an index)
Now I want to add the two:

```
t1 = datetime.now()
vs3 = vs1 + vs2
t2 = datetime.now()
print t2-t1
```

Just the addition runs in 3.8 seconds on my machine, the results I have given doesn't include the object initializaion time at all, its only the addition code that has been timed. If I run the same thing using numpy arrays:

```
nv1 = Series(map(lambda x: 2.0*x-1.0, range(0,n)))
nv2 = Series(map(lambda x: 2.0*x+1.0, range(0,n)))

t3 = datetime.now()
nv3 = numpy.sqrt((nv1*nv1+nv2*nv2))
t4 = datetime.now()
print t4-t3
```

It runs in 0.03 seconds. That's more than 100 times faster!

As you can see, the OOP way gives me a lot of security that people won't be adding Volatility the wrong way, but the vector method is just so crazy fast! Is there a design in which I can get both? I am sure a lot of you have run into similar design choices, how did you work it out?

The choice of language here is immaterial. I know a lot of you would advise that use C++ or Java, and the code may run faster than vector based languages anyway. But that's not the point. I need to use Python, because I have a host of libraries not available in other languages. That's my constraint. I need to optimize within it.

And I know, that a lot of people would suggest parallelization, gpgpu etc. But I want to maximize single core performance first, and then I can parallelize both the versions of code.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So, what's the question? Can you get both OOP and speed? No, this is a tradeoff.

Comment: Your code won't work -- `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'value'` ... and I'm not completely sure what your question is here.  Have you considered having `Volatility` objects which hold numpy ndarrays as the `.value`s?

Comment: So define a class called `VolatilityVector` (or whatever) which contains a vector of values, define addition on these things as you wish.  Voila ?

Comment: And by the way, `map()` looks really ugly *and* it is slower than a generator expression. If speed is your concern you should use e.g. `(2.0*x-1.0 for x in range(0,n))` instead. Furthermore, if you are in dire need of speed, as usual in CPython, you should write and optimize the critical parts in C.

Comment: @Evpok: 1. you are right but that part of the code has not been included in the time calculation. If you look carefully its just the addition part that has been profiled (rather crudely). 2. Your idea about using CPython is of course correct, but if I start coding out the "critical parts" in C I will end up coding most of the complicated algorithms provided by Python myself. As I mentioned, I need to work within Python.

Answer (score 3):

A possible solution for these cases is taking a step back: Do you really need or want to represent individual values as objects? What if your objects were entire arrays (or series) of `Volatile`? You get the best of both worlds.

Even if there is some use for individual `Volatile` objects you can implement a [flyweight pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern), where a `Volatile` object would be a mere wrapper of the position in the array and all methods would operate on the array.

Comment: thanks @Joni, if I am correct (my formal knowledge of design patterns is shaky at best), flyweight pattern will help if I have instances that share some common values, which I don't think is the case here. If you think about it, a `Volatility` object is just a `float`, the difference lies in how it behaves under addition with another `Volatility` instance - its not a simple sum. So its the behavior that is different. But please educate me if I am getting the pattern understanding wrong.

Comment: There are several ways of looking at the flyweight pattern. The basic idea is that instead of having several distinct objects, which becomes expensive, you have a limited pool of them, backed by a shared, compact state. This is assuming that individual Volatility objects make sense in the first place: if they are just `float` values the lack the *identity* that is required by OOP theory.

Answer (score 3):

You can have abstraction, encapsulation, code reuse, etc. (through OOP or otherwise) atop of vectorized operations. You just have to choose the right granularity: Your unit abstraction (object) should be multiple values, as to match the vectorized implementation. There is no plural of volatility as far as I know, but for your specific use case there may be a more appropriate term anyway (what does your set of volatility values *mean*?).

Yes, this means performance concerns impact the abstraction and API (but that happens all the time anyway). No, the impact isn't (necessarily) reduced abstraction, or even a leaky abstraction. It merely changes the shape of the abstraction. In fact, this may even result in a more convenient API for the rest of the code, if it only ever operates on all values at once.

Comment: Thanks @delnan, that's a good idea. In fact I have gone that way in my current design in parts, where some objects like monetary amounts were redesigned that way. But soon I realized that my code becomes a slave of that particular data structure. For e.g. If I have a `VolatilitySeries` as you suggest, then I cannot have a `list`, or a `tuple` or (assuming you are familiar with Python) a DataFrame of volatility items. That bothers me, because then my architecture doesn't scale well, and the benefits fade away after a while. And that is what brings me here :)

Comment: The other issue is that nothing is stopping anyone to write a code like `volatilitySeries[0] + 3.0`, which will be wrong. Once you wriggle out values from `VolatilitySeries`, you can go berserk, so safety is only short lived. In a polymorphic environment where people are not always aware of the exact class being used, this is highly possible. And you know, you can only educate your users so much. I know you will say that, hey I can also do the same thing if I wriggle out `Volatility.value`, but you know, at least the user is aware now that he is using a special value.

Comment: Some may also suggest that override all those usual functions inherited from `Series` in `VolatilitySeries`, but that defeats the whole purpose. So what I have learnt from going down that path is that having a `VolatilitySeries` object only really works out in the long run if the individual cells are of type `Volatility`.

Comment: @RamanujLal You seem to assume that such a `VolatilitySeries` would inherit from, and hence include the interface of, a `Series`. That is not necessary, and in fact possibly a bad idea. You can use composition instead of inheritance: `VolatilitySeries` *has a* `Series`, but it *is not a* `Series`. Your other concern, that you can't use other collection of volatility values, is true -- but I am not sure whether this is actually a problem, especially with duck typing. If performance is not a concern, you can do what @Joni suggests. You can even derive such wrapper objects programmatically.